# Добавление Username пользователя из Телеграм в SQLlite в aiogram

Tags: sqlite, aiogram, execute

Доброго времени суток бьюсь с этой проблемой уже больше месяца. Мне нужно чтобы по нажатию инлайн кнопки, добавлялась запись с Username пользователя, продуктом, что он нажал и т д. Делаю корзину товаров, короче говоря. Перепробовал десятки разных вариантов, все заканчивалось тем, что если запишу "username" в скобках, то он отображает в колонке записи текст - "username", если без скобок, то после нажатия кнопки ничего не происходит и ошибки python не выдает, непонятно в какую сторону думать. Я уже понял, что username должен быть без скобок, чтобы он сработал, но как записать уже ума не приложу... На данный момент код выглядит так, выложил последнее, что попробовал. Использую aiogram.
СУБД SQliteStudio. Значение столбца username (INTEGER, NOT NULL)

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text='doner1') 
async def donecallback(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    await call.answer(text="Добавлено в корзину", show_alert=True) 
async def db_message(username):
    db = sqlite3.connect('FShop.db')
    cur = db.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO basket VALUES({},?,?,?)".format(username, 'none', 'Blue Razz Ice', '1'))
    db.commit
    db.close
```

Comment: cur.execute("INSERT INTO basket VALUES(?,?,?,?)", (username, 'none', 'Blue Razz Ice', '1',))

Comment: Я надеюсь у Вас в таблице 4 столбца

Comment: Все верно 4, извиняюсь, что забыл ответить.  Решил вопрос путем добавления переменной 
user_id = call.message.chat.id. Проблема была в том, что я просил обработчика обработать сообщение, а весь массиф находится в Callback  функции. Я добавил call и все заработало